# Error Resetting android.test.purchased

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I'm working on one of my first android apps which has some in-app billing features. I've spent the last 3 days researching how to add these in-app purchases after purchasing my developer's licence. I stumbled across a guide that lead me to success on a test program :

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_Studio_Google_Play_In-app_Billing_Tutorial

The test program works great. But when i applied this guide to my NavigationDrawerFragment Program, I've ran into some issues. Like i said in the title, i'm using android.test.purchased as the SKU and it seems to only let me use the test purchase every now and then.

Other times i get "In-app billing error: Unable to buy item, Error response: 7:Item Already Owned"

I have added the billing permission in the manifest file, I have also made this alteration to the Security.java File (following the guide):

```
public static boolean verifyPurchase(String base64PublicKey,
                                     String signedData, String signature) {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(signedData) ||
            TextUtils.isEmpty(base64PublicKey) ||
            TextUtils.isEmpty(signature)) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Purchase verification failed: missing data.");
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

MainActivity.java - OnCreate - Log.d code is // on purpose

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String base64EncodedPublicKey =
            "My key that i almost pasted in here :P";

    mHelper = new IabHelper(this, base64EncodedPublicKey);

    mHelper.startSetup(new
                               IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
                                   public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result)
                                   {
                                       if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                                           //Log.d(TAG, "In-app Billing setup failed: " +
                                                   //result);
                                       } else {
                                           //Log.d(TAG, "In-app Billing is set up OK");
                                       }
                                   }
                               });

    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    mTitle = getTitle();

    // Set up the drawer.
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
            R.id.navigation_drawer,
            (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
}
```

Rest of MainActivity.java that doesn't have to do with the drawerFragment:

```
private static final String TAG = "com.example.inappbilling";
static final String ITEM_SKU = "android.test.purchased";

public void buyClick(View view) {
    mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, ITEM_SKU, 10001,
            mPurchaseFinishedListener, "mypurchasetoken");
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                Intent data)
{
    if (!mHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode,
            resultCode, data)) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}

IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener
        = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
    public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result,
                                      Purchase purchase)
    {
        if (result.isFailure()) {
            // Handle error
            return;
        }
        else if (purchase.getSku().equals(ITEM_SKU)) {
            consumeItem();
        }
    }
};


public void consumeItem() {
    mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mReceivedInventoryListener);
}

IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mReceivedInventoryListener
        = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
    public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result,
                                         Inventory inventory) {

        if (result.isFailure()) {
            // Handle failure
        } else {
            mHelper.consumeAsync(inventory.getPurchase(ITEM_SKU),
                    mConsumeFinishedListener);
        }
    }
};


IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener mConsumeFinishedListener =
        new IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener() {
            public void onConsumeFinished(Purchase purchase,
                                          IabResult result) {

                if (result.isSuccess()) {
                    //clickButton.setEnabled(true);
                     Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

                    //Never had this code actually run before, could contain errors
                    //but those aren't the issue to my knowledge.
                    SharedPreferences pref = MainActivity.this.getSharedPreferences("MyPref",
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("BoughtTabard",true);
                    editor.commit();
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.container, TabardGuideNeedToBuy.newInstance(8))
                            .commit();

                } else {
                    // handle error
                }
            }
        };


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mHelper != null) mHelper.dispose();
    mHelper = null;
}
```

Not sure if I'm just overlooking a minor issue or something, but any ideas/solutions are greatly appreciated!

And I have indeed added the IInAppBillingService.aidl to the correct spot, along with all 9 of the util files(Base64,Secruity,SkuDeatils ect...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if for some reason android.test.purchased isnt consumed when it's supposed to be, add the consumeItem(); call from in the  if (result.isFailure()), run the app, relaunch the purchase flow, it will then crash and consume android.test.purchased, then go back to the code and remove the consumeItem(); call from within the if (result.isFailure()). Re-run the app once again, and android.test.purchased should now be able to be consumed again.